# Facing error .$ (...) is not a function! in FullCalendar Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used FullCalendar Library with drag&drop option but unfortunately what I got while running the project is an Error called ".$ (...) is not a function". 
Indeed, there are some issues with the project;

1) The top tool bar is not loaded.

2) Drop function does not work. (Drag function is working but Drop is not)

Please also do note that I have already tried replacing jquery with $ sign in the code source as well as $.noConflict(true) function but so far, it still doesnt work.

Comment: Have you checked if jQuery is actually loaded?

Comment: Not much we can do without seeing the code ([mcve]).

Comment: Yes, it worked properly when I took the page to Webstorm but not when its run within the project.

Comment: The FullCalendar is Jqeury. The problem is when I took it to my project, it seems there is a conflict with AngularJS. The $ sign, I believe.